Failing POST Request to AMEX Login
I'm trying to send a POST request to login to AMEX, which would normally be done a web app through https://www.americanexpress.com/en-us/account/login. Logging in normally works.
Observing Chrome Webtools Network - it appears to be sending a
POST request to https://global.americanexpress.com/myca/logon/us/action/login.
My payload, which was observed through Chrome's Webtools is
'UserID': MY_USERNAME,
'Password': MY_PASSWORD,
'request_type': 'login',
'Face': 'en_US',
'Logon': 'Logon',
'version': '4',
'inauth_profile_transaction_id': 'LOGIN-9d976fcf-6f67-446f-a7ce-ef665bc3d902',
'DestPage': 'https%3A%2F%2Fglobal.americanexpress.com%2Fdashboard',
'channel': 'Web',
'REMEMBERME': 'off',
'b_hour': '11',
'b_minute': '45',
'b_second': '38',
'b_dayNumber': '14',
'b_month': '4',
'b_year': '2024',
'b_timeZone': '-5'

My headers is
headers = {
    'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

My request line in Python is
URL_LOGIN = 'https://global.americanexpress.com/myca/logon/us/action/login'
r = requests.post(URL_LOGIN, data=PAYLOAD, headers=headers)

The erroneous result is
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;global&#46;americanexpress&#46;com&#47;myca&#47;logon&#47;us&#47;action&#47;login" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;5fc94d17&#46;1713113139&#46;39df67f
<P>https&#58;&#47;&#47;errors&#46;edgesuite&#46;net&#47;18&#46;5fc94d17&#46;1713113139&#46;39df67f</P>
</BODY>
</HTML>

I understand there may be additional headers required in AMEX's compliance to anti-botting. Though, I see this as no different to logging in through the webapp.
What am I missing?

AMEX URL currrently returns "Our System is Not Responding You may experience intermittent delays. We apologize for this inconvenience.", unable to diagnose until AMEX services are back online.

Thanks, @chickitychinachinesechicken. I'm trying to login to https://www.americanexpress.com/en-us/account/login. Observing Chrome Webtools Network - it appears to send a POST request to 'https://global.americanexpress.com/myca/logon/us/action/login'. Perhaps I'm reading it incorrectly.

Okay, the AMEX services are now back online, will try to diagnose

Perhaps the problem is that you need to do a GET request first, to allow the server to establish cookies, and then do the POST request within the same session.

Thanks, @JohnGordon. I've observed the activity timeline in Chrome Webtools Network. It appears the login POST is called first. Though, I acknowledge there are cookies required, which I don't quite understand.

It appears the login POST is called first I don't understand -- surely you visit a url to display the login form first?  That would be a GET request.  Why do you say the POST is first?

@JohnGordon. First step after clicking the "Log In" button. I understand what you've saying. I'll look into it.
